# Why ActionsObservable in redux-observable are hot observables?

Tags: rxjs, observable, redux-observable

Why **ActionsObservable** in **redux-observable** are **hot observables**?

What should happen if we pass **cold observables** to ActionsObservable?

Senario:

Create an action stream from cold observables. Whenever the epic is "fired" more than once, eg. case 3 in the following example, the **1+N** results are just repeating the result of the first "fire".

If createHotObservable is used, everything will work as expect. I've studied this problem the entire day and I found only some articles glance at the fact that ActionsObservable are **hot observables**.

```
// pseudo code. 
// Normally，the epic will return "SUCCESS" 2 frames after "START". If there's "CANCEL" within 2 frames after "START", the epic will return nothing

ts = new TestScheduler()
values = {
  a: { type: 'START' },
  b: { type: 'SUCCESS'},
  c: { type: 'CANCEL' }
};


// case 1 "success"
let source = ActionsObservable.from(
    ts.createColdObservable('-a-----', values)
);
ts.expectObservable(epic(source)).toBe('---b-', values);

// case 2 "cancel"
let source = ActionsObservable.from(
    ts.createColdObservable('-ac-----', values)
);
ts.expectObservable(epic(source)).toBe('----', values);


// case 3 "success and cancel". Test fail '---b---b-' received！  
let source = ActionsObservable.from(
    ts.createColdObservable('-a---ac--', values)
);
ts.expectObservable(epic(source)).toBe('---b-----', values);
```

It would be grateful if someone can help.